# Setting variable with default value behaves differently when preceding a command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

Setting a variable with a fallback default value works...as long as we're using the variable in a *subsequent* command:

```
$ unset APP_ENV
$ echo $APP_ENV

$ APP_ENV="${APP_ENV:-production}"; echo $APP_ENV
production
$ APP_ENV=staging
$ APP_ENV="${APP_ENV:-production}"; echo $APP_ENV
staging
```

However, trying to set the variable *immediately preceding* the command that uses it behaves differently:

```
$ unset APP_ENV
$ echo $APP_ENV

$ APP_ENV="${APP_ENV:-production}" echo $APP_ENV

$ APP_ENV=staging
$ APP_ENV="${APP_ENV:-production}" echo $APP_ENV
staging
```

Why the second example behaves differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's replace the semicolon with a newline to make the first version clearer:

```
APP_ENV="${APP_ENV:-production}"
echo $APP_ENV
```

Line 1 executes completely before the shell looks at line 2.

Line 1 causes `$APP_ENV` to be set equal to `production`.

Line 2 accesses that variable and provided its value to the `echo` command.

Now the single-command version:

```
APP_ENV="${APP_ENV:-production}" echo $APP_ENV
```

First the shell expands the command line according to parameter expansion and (not applicable in this case) other kinds of substitution. Since the current value of `$APP_ENV` is empty, that expands to:

```
APP_ENV="${:-production}" echo
```

After performing expansions, it sets the variable `$APP_ENV` to `production` for this command invocation only, and invokes `echo ""` with that value. But `echo` doesn not care that it got an environment varible `$APP_ENV` in its environment. It only looks at its command line, which consists of nothing. So it echoes nothing.

Here's how you prove that `$APP_ENV` really is being set in this case:

```
$ APP_ENV="${APP_ENV:-production}" env |grep APP_ENV
APP_ENV=production
```

In summary, your second example does not do what you thought it would do because the parameter expansion happens too soon.

Comment: Thank you for breaking that down, it makes perfect sense to me now!

Answer (score -4):

The second form is behaving differently because you're missing a `;` after the variable initialization:

```
APP_ENV="${APP_ENV:-production}" echo $APP_ENV
```

should be:

```
APP_ENV="${APP_ENV:-production}"; echo $APP_ENV
                                ^ semicolon that's missing
```

Fix that first, then restate your question.

Comment: Yes, it's a different command without the semicolon. That's the point of the question. The question is valid as it stands.